# checkbox in pageablelistview in wicket

Tags: wicket

```
    private ArrayList<MFRList> list;
private ArrayList<STUList>  list1 = new ArrayList<STUList>();


public ResultPage(PageParameters params) throws APIException {

 Form form = new Form("form");
    PageableListView view = new PageableListView("view", list, 10) {

        @Override
        public void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            setVisible(list.size() > 0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {

            final StuList stu= (StuList) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new CheckBox("check", item.getModel()));
            item.add(new Label("name", stu.getName()));
            item.add(new Label("num", stu.getNumber()));
            item.add(new Label("age", stu.getAge()));
            item.add(new Label("sex", stu.getSex()));
        }
    };

    Button backtosearchbutton = new Button("backtosearchbutton") {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
            setResponsePage(SearchPage.class);
        }
    }.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
    Button groupcheckbutton = new Button("groupcheckbutton") {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
        }
    }.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
    Button groupuncheckbutton = new Button("groupuncheckbutton") {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
        }
    }.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
    Button submitselectionbutton = new Button("submitselectionbutton") {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
        }
    }.setDefaultFormProcessing(true);
    form.add(view);
    form.add(backtosearchbutton);
    form.add(submitselectionbutton);
    form.add(groupuncheckbutton);
    form.add(groupcheckbutton);
    add(form);
    add(new CustomPagingNavigator("navigator", view));
```

how are the selected records stored and how can i use it. i understand that on form submission these records are submitted but i am not clear on how and where.

and my pojo is

```
public class MFRList implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String num;
private String age;
private String sex;
private Boolean selected = Boolean.FALSE;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

public String getnum() {
    return num;
}

public void setnum(String num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setsex(String sex) {
    this.sex= sex;
}

public String getsex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setage(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Boolean getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

}
```

where is the selected row saved and how can i retrieve and use it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a CheckGroup with Checks instead:

public ResultPage(PageParameters params) throws APIException {

```
Form form = new Form("form");

CheckGroup selection = new CheckGroup("selection", new ArrayList());
selection.setRenderBodyOnly(false);
form.add(selection);

PageableListView view = new PageableListView("view", list, 10) {

    @Override
    public void onConfigure() {
        super.onConfigure();
        setVisible(list.size() > 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {

        final StuList stu= (StuList) item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new Check("check", item.getModel()));
        item.add(new Label("name", stu.getName()));
        item.add(new Label("num", stu.getNumber()));
        item.add(new Label("age", stu.getAge()));
        item.add(new Label("sex", stu.getSex()));
    }
};
selection.add(view);
```

This way the arrayList passed to the CheckGroup constructor will always contain the selected objects.

Comment: Hi thanks for simple solution i tried this earlier but did a fundamental mistake, now i know where. Now i have another issue i am loosing the selected data stored in the arraylist when i navigate to next set of list using pagination. how do i not loose the data in the arraylist when the list view is paginated?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got what i was trying to acheive but i am not su7re if it is optimal solution.

I created my own Model and added the object to a list when check box is selected.

class SelectedCheckBoxModel extends AbstractCheckBoxModel {

```
  private final STUList info; 
  private ArrayList<STUList> list1; 

public SelectedCheckBoxModel(STUList info, ArrayList<STUList> list1) {
    super();
    this.info = info;
    this.list1 = list1;
}

@Override
public boolean isSelected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return list1.contains(info); 
}

@Override
public void select() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list1.add(info); 

}

@Override
public void unselect() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list1.remove(info);

}
```

and i called it in my listview

```
check = new CheckBox("check", new SelectedCheckBoxModel(stu, list1));
item.add(check);
```

if this is not optimal please suggest

Thank You