# losing data stored in list when next page selected in pageablelistview with checkbox

Tags: wicket

How do I not lose stored data of selected items in a pageable list view with checkbox when I change the page. please view my earlier post for code.

Visit page:
[checkbox in pageablelistview in wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101956/checkbox-in-pageablelistview-in-wicket)

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- store the data using Ajax the moment the checkboxes are set/unset.
- try to prevent the user from leaving the page by javascript. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7080269/461499)

Comment: The first option seems to be more valid. I guess he wants to check multiple items and still be able to paginate through them. A less "overhead" method to achieve this would obviously be to only submit the form when the paging is triggered (so somewhere in ``CustomPagingNavigator`` - simple boolean option if paging should submit the form might be okay for his case)